# Mojolicious url_for: absolute path

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm currently trying to port one of my smaller catalyst apps to Mojolicious
(just for the fun of it).

Say that we are on a page: http://whatever.com/generate.
On that page there is a link to for example "generated"

When using catalyst (with TT templates) and you define the link as

```
uri_for 'generated'
```

it will generate a link to http://whatever.com/generate/generated
But if you define it as

```
uri_for '/generated'
```

it will generate a link to http://whatever.com/generated

I tried to do the same with Mojolicious' url_for, but it seems to work differently.
It doesn't make a differnece wether I call

```
url_for 'generated'
```

or

```
url_for '/generated'
```

both calls generate a link to '/generate/generated'

So my question is: how do I make url_for generate a link to an absolute route.
i.e. to '/generated'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`url_for` generates urls relative to app root. That was done for portability: you may place your app at any url and your links won't get broken.

If you need an link to absolute path, why do you need url_for than? You can use just a string `'/generated'`.

From other hand, if you really need Mojo::URL object you can get it with

```
<%= url_for->path('/generated') %>
```

`url_for` when called without params returns current url

Comment: Indeed. I guess I'm still in a catalyst mindset, always using uri_for. But you're right, I don't need url_for at all :-)

Answer (score 12):

You can easily get an absolute url from url_for. It returns a Mojo::URL object, so you can just use the to_abs method:

```
$ perl -Mojo -E 'a("/" => sub { $s=shift;$s->render(text=>$s->url_for("/")->to_abs) })->start' get /
http://localhost:13733/
```